# What normal form is a Star schema model in Data Warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema, star-schema-datawarehouse

In Data warehouse - dimensional modelling, what kind of normal form is Star Schema?

Answer (score 1):

It's not. It is a denormalised model

Comment: It does provide an answer. The questioner asked what normal form a star schema was and I replied that it wasn’t a normal form - how is that not an answer?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sorry 

Comment: Not a problem, no worries

Answer (score 1):

Logical all star schema will be 2nd normal form .

AS **"A relation that is in First Normal Form and every non-primary-key attribute is fully functionally dependent on the primary key, then the relation is in Second Normal Form"**